# Convert nullable int to int in linq query return anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, nullable

here simple linq to entities query that return `anonymous type`. The problem is that one of the `int?` values used like parameter to get another value that is `int`.

All ways that I know is not working. Please advise how to solve this problem.

```
public IQueryable<toursistdata> GetxTouristByCategory(string category)
        {
            var now = System.DateTime.MinValue;
            int i;
            switch (category)
            {
                case "arrival":
                    now = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
                    var arrival = from a in db.xTourist
                                  where a.ArrDate >= now && a.Room == null
                                  select new toursistdata
                                  {
                                      kodt = a.Kod,
                                      name = a.Name,
                                      paxad = a.Paxad,
                                      paxch = a.Paxch,
                                      **//Here is h.Kod is int but KodH is int?**
                                      hotel = (from h in db.Address where h.Kod = (int)a.KodH.HasValue select h.NameC).FirstOrDefault(),
                                      room = a.Room,
                                      arrdate = a.ArrDate,
                                      arrtime = a.ArrTime,
                                      arrflight = a.ArrFl,
                                      depdate = a.DepDate,
                                      deptime = a.Deptime,
                                      depflight = a.DepFlight,
                                      transfer = a.Transfer
                                  };
                                  return arrival;
                case "inhouse":
                    now = System.DateTime.Today;
                    //return db.xTourist.AsQueryable().Where(p => p.Датапр >= now && p.Номер != null).OrderByDescending(p => p.Датапр);
                default:
                    //return db.xTourist.AsQueryable();
            }
        }
```

Comment: In which line is the problem?

Comment: Never use non-english chars in code.

Comment: 'db.Адреса' and others are mistakes by their own.

Comment: It's not the problem for sure. This working fine in other place.

Comment: @AgentFire Technically, there is nothing wrong with it. There is unicode support…

Comment: @andrey.shedko Can you show the declaration for the type of `a`? Which properties are nullable?

Comment: @andrey.shedko why you think it return anonymous type?

Comment: `a.KodH.HasValue` is bool, not int

Comment: You're right guys, I did tried many ways, so a bit confused now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First there is one '=' missing in your equals operator. Then, if You want to compare an int with an int? you can use the Null Coalescing operator ?? to provide a default value for the null-case <s>, then cast it to an int</s>:

```
h.Kod == (a.KodH ?? 0)
```

Comment: No need to explicitly cast to `int`

Comment: Still the same error - cannot convert int to boolean.

Comment: Did You added the second '=' ? It should be 'h.Kod == ', Your code is 'h.Kod ='.

Answer (score 2):

The faulty line should read

- If you're sure the nullable int has a value

`from h in db.Адреса where h.Kod = a.KodH.Value select h.NameC).FirstOrDefault()`

- or if the nullable can be null then use a default value

`from h in db.Адреса where h.Kod = (a.KodH ?? -1) select h.NameC).FirstOrDefault()`

-or-

`from h in db.Адреса 
where a.KodH!= null && h.Kod= a.KodH.Value 
select h.NameC).FirstOrDefault()`

For more details on working with nullable types refer to [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)